# When querying Solr 8.2.0, a NoClassDefFoundError org/apache/zookeeper/server/ByteBufferInputStream is thrown

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, noclassdeffounderror

I'm migrating from Solr 6.0.1 to Solr 8.2.0, with java.
I've been through the major changes pages: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/major-changes-in-solr-7.html#major-changes-in-solr-7
and
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/major-changes-in-solr-8.html#major-changes-in-solr-8

I corrected the code and modified the schema accordingly.

I can launch my Solr instance and I see my different cores, as in the 6.0.1 version. So everything looks fine.

But whenever I'm querying Solr I get an exception.

`httpSolrClient.deleteByQuery("*:*")` leads to this exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/server/ByteBufferInputStream`

I'm using maven to handle all the dependencies and I have solr-core and solrJ both in version 8.2.0.

Here is the stackTrace:

```
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:673)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:262)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:245)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:211)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:940)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:903)
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:918)
```

If you have any clues... thank you !

Comment: Seems like you're missing the ZooKeeper libraries. [According to the pom file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/solr/solr-solrj/8.2.0/solr-solrj-8.2.0.pom), that should be fetched as well. Are you adding the appropriate libraries or paths when running your application?

Comment: I have Zookeeper libraries in my classpath

Comment: According to the error message you don't - but extract the jar file and check if the ByteBufferInputStream class is present in that case. There might be a version incompatibility.